# Image field, how add title field?

Tags: 8, media

Here drupal have a field for set a description for each images:

[image]

How I can add a custom field for each image please ?
By example a "Title" or "Author" field ?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not understand your question..can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: I mean you want to add title text field replacing in alternative text field?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried "[ImageField Extended](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended)"? Alternatively, you could create a new content type which consists of an image and any number of fields that you want.

Comment: The question is tagged with 8 and you've linked a module thats last supported version is Drupal 6.